# How to add utf-8 chars to DataMatrix?

Tags: java

Problem is i need to use utf-8 chars in datamatrix. Any chance to add utf-8 characters to the datamatrix? I know about extensions like ECI = 22 for adding UTF-8, but how to realize this? Maybe with itextpdf.barcodes.BarcodeDataMatrix i can do this, but i don't find examples.

Comment: Have you tried to `mextrix.setOptions(BarcodeDataMatrix.DM_RAW); matrix.setEncoding("UTF-8")` ?

Comment: Thanks, i'll try.

Comment: Not working also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with okapibarcode (https://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode)

```
uk.org.okapibarcode.backend.DataMatrix dataMatrix = new uk.org.okapibarcode.backend.DataMatrix();
    dataMatrix.setFontName("Helvetica");
    dataMatrix.setFontSize(11);
    dataMatrix.setModuleWidth(2);
    dataMatrix.setBarHeight(50);
    dataMatrix.setContent("тест");

    int width = dataMatrix.getWidth();
    int height = dataMatrix.getHeight();

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    Java2DRenderer renderer = new Java2DRenderer(g2d, 1, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.render(dataMatrix);
    return image;
```